# Play sounds with loop on the old browsers

Tags: html, internet-explorer, embed, internet-explorer-6

I need to play a sound on all browsers ( so I have to use the object tag ).

The loop doesn't work. 
Why ?

This is my code:

```
<object height="0px" width="0px" data="audio.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" >
<param name="autostart" value="true" />
<param name="loop" value="true" />
<param name="src" value="audio.mp3"/>
<embed src="audio.mp3" autostart="false" loop="true">
</object>
```

Comment: What "old browser" are you referring to? You need to be more specific

Comment: I mean internet explorer 6

Answer (score 2):

For such an old browser, maybe you can fall back to the `<bgsound>` element. This element is non-standard, but still the guys at [Mozilla took the time to describe it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/bgsound).

In summary, so set a source and specify an infinite loop:

```
<bgsound src="sound2.au" loop="infinite">
```

You can add such an element using JavaScript.

For other browsers, including modern versions of Internet Explorer (9 and up), it's best to use the `<audio>` tag, also [documented by Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio).

The `audio` tag supports inner content that is used when the browser doesn't support it. That feature can be used for the `bgsound` fallback, like so:

```
<audio src="sound.ogg" autoplay loop>
  <bgsound src="sound.au" loop="infinite">
</audio>
```

Note that you will likely have to have the sound available in multiple formats if you want to make it playable on all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

When you embed this way, the behavior is dependent on the plugin loaded to handle the media.  There is no guarantee that loop or autostart are respected by the player that the user has installed.  They should be considered as suggestions or hints to the player as to what it should do, and nothing more.

You will have more predictable behavior with Flash, which most folks with older browsers have installed.